# Tab-Bar app crashes when switching from one tab to another

Tags: iphone, crash, uitabbarcontroller, nszombie

I'm getting this error:

```
"An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated object (zombie) at address: 0x118208a0"
```

when I'm switching from one tab to another in my 5-tab app.

The app is set-up in manner similar to the Music/iTunes app we all have on our devices: 5 tabs, each one containing a UINavigationController linking to other screens.

This crash ***only*** happens when I do the following:
 
   -I click on the "MORE" tab
   -select the "Image Gallery" option in it
   -this opens the "ImageGallery" viewController (via a "presentModalViewController" - not a  "pushViewController" - but I don't think this has anything to do with causing the crashing)
    -I then close "ImageGallery" (which has a button triggering a [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] action) - and that brings me back to the "MORE" tab.
   -If I now switch to the "HOME" tab -- CRASH!

This ONLY happens when I switch from "MORE" tab to the "HOME" tab. It doesn't happen on any other tab-switching, AND
-this ONLY happens after I've visited "ImageGallery" in my "MORE" tab.
In other words, if I'm in "MORE" and select any of the other options - which navigate to other screens - and *then* switch to the "HOME" tab - everything is fine. Its only after visiting "ImageGallery" inside of "MORE" and switching to "HOME" (and only "HOME") - that I crash.

Instruments with NSZombies enabled shows this:
[image]

So this obviously happens on call to the "ImageGallery" view-controller from inside the "MORE" view-controller. But with the error being "message was sent to a deallocated object", what doesn't make sense is why/how/when any sort of message ever gets sent to "ImageGallery" from the "HOME" tab in the first place.  Cause the "HOME" tab doesn't ever call or reference or even know about "ImageGallery". And why is it happening only when switching to the "HOME" tab and not any of the 3 other tabs in the app?

Any ideas? (and what does the 86.2% next to the red-highlighted line in the image grab mean?)

Comment: Have you tried the "Product->Analyze" menu item in Xcode to see if it suggests anything to be fixed?

Comment: I did do an "Analyze" (I checked *everything*) - no luck.  I'm beginning to suspect that Instruments is not giving me a totally 100% accurate diagnosis of the situation. There might be an issue with an extern variable called "ImageObjectsArray" - which is declared in MAIN - and which "ImageGallery" also uses. I think maybe when "ImageGallery" is dealloc'd and things go back to "HOME" - which is called by MAIN, the dog-doo hits the fan...

Comment: I'm surprised that it's not giving you the variable class and selector name since the runtime is able to provide those in a NSException.  Maybe wrap the problem code in @try/@catch and use the exception description and callStackSymbols for clues instead of this.

Comment: ok - I'm not familiar with "callStackSymbols" - but I'll try the @try/@catch bit and see what happens (and I'll look up "callStackSymbols" and see what it is/how its used.)

Comment: I *have* gotten this a few times: `-[NSMachPort scrollViewDidScroll:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdebec90`  (This error was displayed in the Console window of course, not in Instruments.) But its been very inconsistent. Most crashes give me errors like this: `code=1, address=0xcc000f37` or `code=1, address=0x8` Here's another variation of that error: ` *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellContentView scrollViewDidScroll:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfe73770'`  The errors have been quite inconsistent.

Comment: So notice that one time it said `-[NSMachPort scrollViewDidScroll:]:` and the second time it said `-[UITableViewCellContentView scrollViewDidScroll:]:`   The only thing consistent there is the `scrollViewDidScroll` portion...

Comment: So, what I think it's telling you is: the object that is supposed to get the `scrollViewDidScroll:` message has been deallocated and the memory has been used for something else.  That makes it sound as if you have a UIScrollViewDelegate that's still getting called after it goes away.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13270/discussion-between-sirab333-and-phillip-mills)

Comment: Yes, the "ImageGalleryVC" (VC = View-Controller) has a scrollView object in it, and I do implement `scrollViewDidScroll` on it there. But when "ImageGalleryVC" goes away, so does the scrollView object in it - and its never called for again anywhere else but in the "ImageGalleryVC", which in turn is only called by its "parent": the "MORE" tab.  The "HOME" tab has nothing to do with either.  "HOME" never asks or calls for "MORE", or for "ImageGalleryVC" - therefore it never sends a message to these now dealloc'd objects. That's what doesn't make sense.

Comment: It might be timing.  Try setting the scroll view's delegate to nil before leaving the ImageGalleryVC.  (Sorry about chat, I'm doing other things and looking at the computer as I pass it.  :) )

Comment: I think I found the problem: "HOME" & "MORE" both have a scrollView object in 'em - which I created programmatically - and both times I named it "scroller". I think that confused the compiler (or run-time system): when I referred to the "HOME" tab's "scroller" object, it must have thought I was still referring to the same-named "scroller" object of the now-released "ImageGallery" view-controlller - and crashed. So I changed the "ImageGallery"'s scroller's name and now its not crashing. Will keep testing - but I think that was it. (Setting delegate to nil probably would have worked as well :-))

Comment: Please check whether you have released the same object twice, or else if you are using autorelease then remove it and use plain release.